# I want this date picker to choose dates from years between 1990 to 2000

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-datepicker

Can someone help me correct this code. I want to pick dates that are between the years 1990 and 2000 only without allowing other dates like the ones in future to be selected.

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $( "#EmpBirthdate" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "-30"
    });
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: you just need to read the documentation: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    showButtonPanel: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
  yearRange: '1999:2012',
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    minDate: new Date(1999, 10 - 1, 25),
    maxDate: '+30Y',
    inline: true
});
});
 Just added year range option. It should solve the problem
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the min max attributes

[Min Max](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max)

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: value1, maxDate: value2 });
```